# Bazel - Can't compile without import Foundation, UIkit,

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to compile a swift project with Bazel, version 4.2.1.

I have a main project with multiple CocoaPods submodules of my own installed. I have a `WORKSPACE` and a `BUILD` configuration file for the project and another `WORKSPACE` and `BUILD` for each submodule.
I add the secondary workspaces as `local_repository` in the main workspace. I create the submodule build with a swift_library and add it in the main build in `deps`.

If in a `.swift` file, located in the submodule, I create a variable "var dateIni: Date?" I get an error "error: cannot find type Date in scope". I can solve this with "import Foundation" but xcode doesn't need it, I would like to be able to compile in Bazel without having to do these SDK frameworks imports. Is there any way to solve this?

I can post code or explain it better if you need more information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same problem, did you find a solution?